# Grub2 cannot see my new external USB hard drive, but sees an older one

Tags: boot, grub2, usb

I am trying to boot Ubuntu-studio (current version) from a new Seagate 2TB expansion USB drive on an old system (PC) whose BIOS doesn't know how to boot from USB.  No problems with either the install or running from the LiveCD in general. I used Gparted from a LiveCD session to partition the drive and then installed Ubuntu to it and everything ended up where I expected.  I set up a Grub boot CD without a config, just to run it interactive for starters, intending to set up a scenario where I can boot the USB from Grub CD initialization.

When I am at the Grub prompt from the rescue CD I do 'ls' to list known devices and Grub sees my internal drive,floppy and CD drives and an older external MAXTOR USB drive, but does not report the new Seagate USB drive or another older USB DVD writer. I have tried unplugging all USB devices, except the Seagate, and it is still not reported by Grub.  Obviously, I can't boot from what I can't point to.

After booting into either WinXP (original system) or with the Ubuntu LiveCD, the Seagate drive is fully visible, writable, mountable,etc..  Any ideas on why Grub can't see it and how to make it visible to Grub? Especially note that Grub *can* see a different USB hard drive on the same system.